# How do I remove a word from a string in an arraylist?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, cpu-word

I have

```
List<String> firstName = new ArrayList<String>()
```

and

```
List<String> lastName = ArrayList<String>()
```

Both holds the **same 10 elements** in the form of `"Foo" + " " + "Bar."`

My question is how do I remove "Foo" from each element in **lastName** and "Bar" from each element in **firstName**?

Comment: `List<<String>String>` is no valid code, or is it?

Comment: Are you sure about your requirement?  You say "remove the Foo", but does that include the space after Foo?  Does "remove the Bar" include the period or not?  It's probably better to state what you want the end result to be, rather than as a change to what's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively like this and avoid having to deal with list indexes which can be prompt to performance issues in certain kind of list implementations which do not guarantee random access (i.e. LinkedList)

```
ListIterator<String> it = firstNames.listIterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()){
   it.set(it.next().split(" ")[0])
}

it = lastNames.listIterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()){
   it.set(it.next().split(" ")[1])
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that it works for "firstName," but still shows "foo" for "lastName"

Comment: In that case either you premises are wrong or you did not do exactly what I did. I have edited to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Well, Strings are immutable, so if you're going to change the strings at ALL in the lists, you're really going to replace the strings in each list with new strings, so it's not as hard as you might think.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < firstName.size(); i++ ) {
    String [] parts = firstName.get(i).split(" ");
    firstName.set( i, parts[0] ); 
}
for ( int i = 0; i < lastName.size(); i++ ) {
    String [] parts = lastName.get(i).split(" ");
    lastName.set( i, parts[1] ); 
}
```

I still don't like pretending I know that both arrays have the same length, so I'm still doing the work twice here.  Girish's answer works too.

Comment: I realize I could have used one loop, but I really don't like assuming they're the same size, when what I'm doing to each array really doesn't have anything to do with each other.

Comment: It's not clear each String has "Foo" and "Bar" in it. Seems like those are examples and could be any variable length String. So you'd need to get the length of those substrings. This is why I used split instead.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not just "foo" and "bar." Names are variable in length of characters

Comment: Sure, I could see it being read the way you answer it with split().  He did say they started off as containing the same elements.

Comment: Ah, ok, Choco.  Perhaps change your question to explain that?  I'll change my answer, but it's going to look pretty similar to Girish's.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through one List. When iterating through firstName, split each of the 10 strings on the white space " " and push the first token back into the firstName List. Push the second token into lastName List.

```
for(int i=0; i < firstName.size(); i++){
    String name = firstName.get(i);
    String[] tokens = name.split(" ");
    String first = tokens[0];
    String last = tokens[1];
    firstName.set(i, first);  //firstName.set(i, first + " ") to keep the whitespace
    lastName.set(i, last); //lastName.set(i, " " + last) to keep the whitespace
}
```

This should work, if as you say, each List contains the same 10 elements.

Comment: This actually doesn't match what he says are the requirements, but probably does what he actually wants.  Your code would get rid of the space between the Foo and Bar altogether, which he never mentions in his requirement.

Comment: Edited to account for whitespace if he wants to keep it

Comment: Hey, Girish... Please GOD don't use variable names that match other variables except for case.  That's what makes typo's like the one in your firstName.set(i, firstName) where the 2nd firstName should be firstname... confusing, no?